# Python_SpeedGauge needle not updating slider value

Tags: python, wxpython

i created a speedmeeter(analog gauge) where the needle should take the value of the slider associated. I run the code and the needle stays at the initial value of the slider (50 here)
can someone help? thanks

```
import wx
import os
import wx.lib.agw.speedmeter as SM
import sys
import math



class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        # creation du panneau
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,-1,"test")



        speed = SM.SpeedMeter(self, agwStyle=SM.SM_DRAW_HAND|SM.SM_DRAW_SECTORS|SM.SM_DRAW_MIDDLE_TEXT|SM.SM_DRAW_SECONDARY_TICKS)

        # Set The Region Of Existence Of SpeedMeter 
        speed.SetAngleRange(-math.pi/6, 11*math.pi/6)

        # SpeedMeter In Sectors
        intervals = range(0, 201, 20)
        speed.SetIntervals(intervals)

        # Assign The Same Colours To All Sectors 
        # Usually This Is Black
        colours = [wx.BLACK]*10
        speed.SetIntervalColours(colours)

        # Assign The Ticks
        ticks = [str(interval) for interval in intervals]
        speed.SetTicks(ticks)
        # Set The Ticks/Tick Markers Colour
        speed.SetTicksColour(wx.WHITE)
        # We Want To Draw 5 Secondary Ticks Between The Principal Ticks
        speed.SetNumberOfSecondaryTicks(5)

        # Set The Font For The Ticks Markers
        speed.SetTicksFont(wx.Font(7, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL))

        # Set The Text In The Center Of SpeedMeter
        speed.SetMiddleText("Km/h")
        # Assign The Colour To The Center Text
        speed.SetMiddleTextColour(wx.BLACK)
        # Assign A Font To The Center Text
        speed.SetMiddleTextFont(wx.Font(8, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))

        # Set The Colour For The Hand Indicator
        speed.SetHandColour(wx.Colour(255, 50, 0))

        # Do Not Draw The External (CONTAINER) Arc
        speed.DrawExternalArc(False)

        #set gauge to initial slider position
        #self.pos=self.slider.GetValue()

        #creation ofslider

        self.slider=wx.Slider(speed,-1,50,0,150,pos=(15,415),size=  (350,-1),style=wx.SL_AUTOTICKS|wx.SL_LABELS)
        self.slider.SetTickFreq(5,1)

        #value of needle

        val=self.slider.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER,self.sliderUpdate)

    def sliderUpdate(self, event):
        #get slider position
        val=self.slider.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER,self.sliderUpdate)
        self.pos=self.slider.GetValue()


APP=wx.App(0)

frame=MyFrame(None)
APP.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()
APP.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not set up the event handler `sliderUpdate` to set the value of the speedometer. You need to make the speedometer variable `speed` a class attribute. I made the necessary changes to the code.

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        # creation du panneau
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,-1,"test")

        self.speed = SM.SpeedMeter(self, agwStyle=SM.SM_DRAW_HAND|SM.SM_DRAW_SECTORS|SM.SM_DRAW_MIDDLE_TEXT|SM.SM_DRAW_SECONDARY_TICKS)

        # Set The Region Of Existence Of SpeedMeter 
        self.speed.SetAngleRange(-math.pi/6, 11*math.pi/6)

        # SpeedMeter In Sectors
        intervals = range(0, 201, 20)
        self.speed.SetIntervals(intervals)

        # Assign The Same Colours To All Sectors 
        # Usually This Is Black
        colours = [wx.BLACK]*10
        self.speed.SetIntervalColours(colours)

        # Assign The Ticks
        ticks = [str(interval) for interval in intervals]
        self.speed.SetTicks(ticks)
        # Set The Ticks/Tick Markers Colour
        self.speed.SetTicksColour(wx.WHITE)
        # We Want To Draw 5 Secondary Ticks Between The Principal Ticks
        self.speed.SetNumberOfSecondaryTicks(5)

        # Set The Font For The Ticks Markers
        self.speed.SetTicksFont(wx.Font(7, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL))

        # Set The Text In The Center Of SpeedMeter
        self.speed.SetMiddleText("Km/h")
        # Assign The Colour To The Center Text
        self.speed.SetMiddleTextColour(wx.BLACK)
        # Assign A Font To The Center Text
        self.speed.SetMiddleTextFont(wx.Font(8, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))

        # Set The Colour For The Hand Indicator
        self.speed.SetHandColour(wx.Colour(255, 50, 0))

        # Do Not Draw The External (CONTAINER) Arc
        self.speed.DrawExternalArc(False)

        #set gauge to initial slider position
        #self.pos=self.slider.GetValue()

        #creation ofslider
        self.slider=wx.Slider(self.speed,-1,50,0,150,pos=(15,415),size=  (350,-1),style=wx.SL_AUTOTICKS|wx.SL_LABELS)
        self.slider.SetTickFreq(5,1)

        #binding the event of slider change
        self.slider.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER,self.sliderUpdate)

    def sliderUpdate(self, event):
        #get slider position and set it on speedometer
        self.speed.SetSpeedValue(self.slider.GetValue())
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how do i assign different colors to the sectors? for example if i would like to set half of it black and the other half red. should i tried in vain the followin colours=([wx.BLACK]*5,[wx.RED]*5]

Comment: my last question in wxpython. i included  a second slider and speedometer on the same frame. Running my app will show only the sliders and 2 dots. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by the dots? The speedometer?

Comment: yes i believe the dots (2 black dots) above each sliders represent the speedometers. but it is not possible to distinguish anything.

Comment: I had to set a fix position and size for each of the speedometer. Like this both appear at the place set in the code. I will keep on searching as well for the sectors colors

Comment: I'll try rectifying your code in the other question. You might want to accept this as an answer.